Finite differencing for velocity cross terms?
In writing down the Navier-Stokes equation I have encountered two equations  as follows:
$$ 4\frac{\partial^2 v_x}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v_x}{\partial y^2} + 3\frac{\partial^2 v_y}{\partial x\partial y} -v_x = -\partial_xf(x) $$
$$ 4\frac{\partial^2 v_y}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v_y}{\partial x^2} + 3\frac{\partial^2 v_x}{\partial x\partial y} -v_y = -\partial_yf(x) $$
$f(x)$ is a known function and we want to find the velocity fields. I am trying to use finite differencing on this equation and invert the matrix to numerically find out the solution.  How do I finite difference the 3rd term in both the equations, i.e. the mixed partial derivative terms of the velocity?

Probably the most easy way to arrive at the finite difference scheme for a cross term is to separate the partial derivatives into two operations on the velocity (assuming forward differencing):
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}\right)\to\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{v_y(x,y+\Delta y)-v_y(x,y)}{\Delta y}\right)$$
And then we can apply the $\partial_x$ term to both $v_y$ terms:
$$\frac{\partial^2 v_y}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{1}{\Delta y}\left[\frac{v_y(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)-v_y(x,y+\Delta y)}{\Delta x}-\frac{v_y(x+\Delta x,y)-v_y(x,y)}{\Delta x}\right]$$
Using backwards or central differencing should be straight-forward from here; if you are careful, higher-order schemes can also be determined in the same fashion.
You should also take the time to ensure that if you reverse the operations (i.e., take the partial derivative with respect to $x$ first, then $y$), you arrive at the same equation (though the terms may be out of order).

Lets say If I have done Forward Differencing for double derivatives then we need to do the same for cross terms ?

They don't have to be the same, but just remember that the accuracy of the simulation will be limited to the lowest-order scheme; so if you're using $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)$ scheme for one term and $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x)$ scheme for another another, your scheme is $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x)$ overall.
